# How do I make subsonic (media server) work with SSL?

Tags: media, subsonic

The roughly out-of-the-box setup as a regular user works fine (meaning the site appears at http://myserver.com:4040).  From `ps aux`

```
java -Xmx100m -Dsubsonic.home=/var/subsonic -Dsubsonic.host=0.0.0.0 -Dsubsonic.port=4040 -Dsubsonic.httpsPort=0 -Dsubsonic.contextPath=/ -Dsubsonic.defaultMusicFolder=/var/music -Dsubsonic.defaultPodcastFolder=/var/music/Podcast -Dsubsonic.defaultPlaylistFolder=/var/playlists -Djava.awt.headless=true -verbose:gc -jar subsonic-booter-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

but just giving an https port

```
java -Xmx100m -Dsubsonic.home=/var/subsonic -Dsubsonic.host=0.0.0.0 -Dsubsonic.port=4040 -Dsubsonic.httpsPort=6060 -Dsubsonic.contextPath=/ -Dsubsonic.defaultMusicFolder=/var/music -Dsubsonic.defaultPodcastFolder=/var/music/Podcast -Dsubsonic.defaultPlaylistFolder=/var/playlists -Djava.awt.headless=true -verbose:gc -jar subsonic-booter-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

makes http://myserver.com:4040 say

```
HTTP ERROR: 404
NOT_FOUND
RequestURI=/index.view
Powered by jetty://
```

and https://myserver.com:6060 say

```
Unable to connect
```

I'm only making the change by doing

```
# SUBSONIC_ARGS="--port=80 --https-port=443 --max-memory=120"
SUBSONIC_ARGS="--max-memory=100 --https-port=6060"
```

in `/etc/default/subsonic` and issuing a
`sudo service subsonic restart` (this is Ubuntu Oneiric)

Comment: I have subsonic set up on a netbook, that unfortunately isn't running right now. When I get home and get it fixed up, I'll see if I can get ssh to work. You might be interested in the supersonic project on github, https://github.com/Mach5/supersonic/

Comment: Did you setup SSL certificates?  After restarting the service, do you see subsonic listening to the SSL port?  See `netstat -ntlp`.